Questions about Alfred Noyes' Midnight Express #2: who was (were) the doppelgänger(s)?
I have this(these) question(s) regarding Alfred Noyes' "Midnight Express"
Because I have about ten questions regarding this, I will post each individually.
I am not giving any exerpt because I think the story itself is so complicated and intricately interconnected that it is best to give the story a quick read. So here's my second doubt:

Who is that "double" or "triple"(?) doppelganger of Mortimer?

I mean, yeah, sure they are Mortimer's doppelgangers, but are they real, or his subconsciously-created-virtually-real(or, really-virtual?)-kind-of-supernatural beings? Why is he afraid of them? How are all things related??? What happened to them later on? Was Mortimer destined to pass all these three phases of life? Will he later on see himself again, give shelter to himself again???
It's all so confusing. Or is I'm confusing myself?
I have read the story so many times but still I can't make the head and tail out of the story. These are the questions lingering in my mind ever since I read the story. I found no satisfactory answers in the internet.
Thanks in advance!

I actually have about ten questions regarding the story. At first I wrote all the ten questions in a single page, but someone commented that it was best to put each of them one by one having different pages, hence the numberings #1,#2, etc. But I can't continue to write the other questions because the site doesn't allow to put consecutive questions within 40 minutes. The numbering is just to remind me what numbered question I am asking. I have added a link which shows the original story. Since the story itself is very complicated, I don't think anyone can understand anything from any exerpt.

@FKcosθ: There's nothing wrong with numbering the questions, but please try to give them names as well, like "Questions about Alfred Noyes' Midnight Express #2: who was (were) the doppelgänger(s)?" (although you should choose your own name for the question if you don't like my suggestion). Otherwise somebody answering one might have to look through all ten questions before finding the correct one.

Ok, I have edited both of my questions according to your suggestions.

Thanks for updating the questions, they look better. I still disagree about quoting some relevant extracts. You're right that people need to read the story before they can answer the question. But I think people are more likely to do that if you quote. Take some time and read through other questions on the site and see which ones draw you in and make you read the work.
